# Ответить что значит последний вариант

Tags: c++

Имеет исходную строку в коде

```
Folder operator +( Folder )
{
    //тело метода (функции)
}
```

(на тело на самом деле наплевать)
Интересует способ записи заголовка функции
Имеем 4 предложенных способа, которые можно подставить вместо исходного варианта:

```
1) Folder operator +( Folder & f)
2) Folder operator +( const Folder & f)
3) const Folder operator +( const Folder & f)
4) const Folder operator +( const Folder & f) const
```

Если первые 3 я примерно понимаю что значит, то последний я не имею представления, прошу объяснить мне.
Заранее спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Folder operator +( Folder & f)         // Передана ссылка
Folder operator +( const Folder & f)   // Передана константная ссылка
const Folder operator +( const Folder & f)  // Передана константная ссылка,
                                            // возвращается константный объект 
const Folder operator +( const Folder & f) const  // Передана константная ссылка,
                                                  // возвращается константный объект,
                                                  // сам оператор константный 
                                                  // - т.е. не меняет текущий объект
```

Так понятно или подробнее?

Вот [пример кода](https://ideone.com/HK5Cr0):

```
class Test
{
public:
    Test operator + (Test&) { cout << "1\n"; return Test(); }
    Test operator + (const Test&) { cout << "2\n"; return Test(); }
    Test operator + (const Test&) const { cout << "3\n"; return Test(); }
};

const Test f() { return Test(); }

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Test a, b;

    a + b;
    a + f();
    f() + f();

}
```

который выводит:

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: то есть в 4 случае, в качестве "левого" операнда служит константная функция? (или любая другая константа?)

Comment: Главное, что в 4 случае левый операнд может быть константным (в первых трех он не может быть константным. Вы фактически говорите - этот оператор будет менять состояние левого операнда)